# Unable to bind event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind an onchange event to a textarea, but this isnt working

```
$('#Que_dlist_ctl0' + sectionid + '_Inner_dlist tr:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')  
#Que_dlist_ctl0' + sectionid + '_Inner_dlist_ctl0' + i + '_txtsuggest')
.addClass("clTxt_" + i)
.bind("change",function(){"Validate(this);"});
```

In the rendered html, I can see the 'class' added as desired, but not the event.
Also tried `.attr` instead of `bind`.

```
$('#Que_dlist_ctl0' + sectionid + '_Inner_dlist tr:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')  
    #Que_dlist_ctl0' + sectionid + '_Inner_dlist_ctl0' + i + '_txtsuggest')
    .addClass("clTxt_" + i)
    .attr("onchange","Validate(this);"});
```

It doesnt work in firefox, ie and chrome.

The rows in table and the controls, all are dynamically generated, and hence that weird id selector

```
<textarea class="clTxt_0" name="Que_dlist$ctl00$Inner_dlist$ctl00$txtsuggest"  
rows="3" cols="20" id="Que_dlist_ctl00_Inner_dlist_ctl00_txtsuggest"  
style="width:300px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why not jquery way of binding event? `.on('change', function(){ Validate(this); });`

Comment: The jquery event's name is `change`, not `onchange`

Comment: *"In the rendered html, I can see the 'class' added as desired, but not the event."* Event binding is handled in the memory. You won't see it an any HTML representation, unless you use inline event handlers (which you should not). Please post a **complete** example.

Comment: @Felix.I understand. I would like to add it as an attribute `<textarea onchange="validate(this)"/>`. Is this possible.

Comment: OP: This code is a mess. It's taken me a while just to grok what it does. Any chance you could clean it up?

Comment: @Qwerty: Yes it is, but it's considered bad practice. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `$(selector).bind("change",function(){}); or $(selector).change(function(){});`, this is going to bind only to those textareas which are already present in the DOM when the event gets bound to the textarea.

Since your rows are generated dynamically, you can just add a class to the textarea while generating

```
<textarea class="gridTextArea" class="clTxt_0" 
 name="Que_dlist$ctl00$Inner_dlist$ctl00$txtsuggest" rows="3" cols="20" 
 id="Que_dlist_ctl00_Inner_dlist_ctl00_txtsuggest"  style="width:300px;" >
 </textarea>
```

and bind it as below which will bind to all the newly created textareas with in the dynamically created rows.

```
$(document).on("change",".gridTextArea",function(){
//your logic goes here
 });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I followed your idea and added the onchange event in the aspx repeater instead of JS. It's good now. Thank you. But in your case, how can I send the control's id -- eg: `$(document).on("change","textarea",function(this)`{validate(this);} My validate function takes the textbox's id as argument

Comment: you can use $(this).attr("id") to get the id of the textarea which you can use to pass it to your [validate] function.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.change(function(){
   Validate(this);
});
```

Comment: @Qwerty: any error?? try giving alert in validate function in the beginning.

Comment: No error. Checked with alert. It doesnt fire at all

Comment: @Qwerty: would be great if you can share the markup.